# Numeric Value Out of Range error

Tags: ms-access, business-objects

I am doing following calculation against MS Access database but getting the error as shown in screenshot. I have Business Objects as fron end tool and database as MS Access. I have tried with Round(value,2) around this operation but no luck. But fields are set as Number with decimal place as 2 at DB level..Appreciate your inputs

[image]

sum(Votes.Value1 * Votes.Value2) / SUM(Votes.Value2)

Comment: Votes.Value1 * Votes.Value2 gets to large if they are summed?

Comment: How should i then avoid this error?